# Check if a formula is a horn clause

Tags: prolog

I made a program in prolog with the operators ~(not), v(or) and ^(and). How can I check if a formula is a horn clause?

For example:

```
?- hclause((A ^ ~B) v (~A ^ C))
true.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add, in your question, a Backus-Naur Form for your Horn clauses? And you want check a formula of terms or is enough check a formula in a string (something like "hclause("(A^~B)v(~A^C)")?

Comment: A formula. It should be able to check every clause.

Comment: sorry but... this doesn't respond my questions. It's enough for you a `hclause/1` that check something like `hclause("(A^~B)v(~A^C)")`, where the formula is in a string? If so, should be simple (a sort of).

Comment: String format isn't enough. :/

Answer (score 3):

Not sure to understand but... if you define `^` and `v` as binary operators and `~` as unary operator, by example

```
:- op(400,  fx, ~).
:- op(500, xfy, ^).
:- op(600, xfy, v).
```

the check of a correct formula should be automatic (giving error otherwise).

Take in count that operator definition is only "Syntactic sugar" and that, by example, `A ^ B` is an alternative version for `^(A, B)`.

If you want to see the real meaning of `(A ^ ~B) v (~A ^ C)` (with this definition for `v`, `^` and `~`), you can use `write_canonical/1`, so with

```
write_canonical((A ^ ~B) v (~A ^ C)),
```

I obtain

```
v(^(_4,~(_7)),^(~(_4),_15))
```